# JAVASCRIPT - append values to one select option of a group o select options

Tags: javascript, php, select

I have a foreach loop that create selects option from a JSON struture.

```
foreach ($categories['results'][0]['parameters'] as $key => $value) {
                if(in_array($value['code'], $input_valid_names)){
                    switch ($value['type']) {
                        case 'select':
                        echo "<div class='coluna-2'>";
                        $options = [];
                        foreach ($value['options'] as $option_value => $option_name) {
                            $option = "<option data-marca='".$option_value."' value='".$option_value."'>".$option_name['pt']."</option>'";
                            array_push($options, $option);
                        }
                        echo "<label>".$value['labels']['pt'].(($value['required'])? '*' : '')."</label>";
                        echo "<select id='sel' name='".$value['code']."' ".(($value['required'])? 'required' : '').">";
                        echo "<option value>Escolha uma opção</option>";
                        foreach ($options as $o) {
                            echo $o;
                        }
                        echo "</select>";
                        echo "<br/><br/>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        break;

                        default:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

In one of this select options that has a label **Modelo**, i need to inject data from an ajax response:

```
success: function(data) {
        var obj0 = JSON.parse(data);
        var obj = obj0.options;
        for (var key in obj){
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.innerHTML = obj[key].pt;
            opt.value = obj[key].pt;
            sel.appendChild(opt);
        }
    }
```

[image: Select Option group generated in foreach loop]

But, if possible, i could not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you call .appendChild on an undefined variable, sel:

```
sel.appendChild(opt);
```

Define this variable like so:

```
success: function(data) {
    var obj0 = JSON.parse(data);
    var obj = obj0.options;
    // get by id
    var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
    // or get by name
    var sel = document.getElementsByName('name')[0];
    for (var key in obj){
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = obj[key].pt;
        opt.value = obj[key].pt;
        sel.appendChild(opt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i know. I now have the getElementById working, but i need to only inject data from the ajax response in the select option that has the label Modelo (you can see it in the image attached). These select options are generated in straight by the foreach loop.

Comment: The hard part is only inject data in the select option that has label called Modelo.

Comment: A pure javascript method could also use document.querySelectorAll("select")[n] where n is the nth select (depending on your html, that one may be 1 or 3) so long as the select elements are always rendered in the same order.